# "Transaction was aborted due to detection of concurrent modification" in FaunaDB

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, faunadb

I have a document that could be written to from many different concurrent requests.. the same section of the document isn't altered, but it could see concurrent writes (from a nodejs app).
example:

```
{
name: "testing",
 results: {
   a: { ... },
   b: { ... },
}
```

I could update the document with "c", etc etc.

If I don't async await the transactions (in a test, for example), I will get partial writes and an error "transaction was aborted due to detection of concurrent modification" .. What's the best way to go about this?  I feel like Fauna's main selling point is dealing with issues like this, but I don't have enough knowledge to understand my way around it.

Anyone have any queue strategies/ideas/suggestions?

index:

```
CreateIndex({
  "name": "byName",
  "unique": true,
  "source": Collection("Testing"),
  "serialized": true,
  "terms": 
    [
      { "field": [ "data", "name" ] }
    ]
})
```

JS AWS Lambda function is what is doing the writing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the unit of transaction in Fauna is the document. So in this case I'd recommend something like the following:

```
CreateCollection({name: "result"})
CreateCollection({name: "sub-result"})
CreateIndex({
  name: "result-agg",
  source: Collection("sub-result"),
  terms: [{"field": ["data", "parent"]}]
})
```

Assuming parent contained the ref of the main result. Then given `$ref` as a result ref

```
Let({
  subs: Select("data", Map(Paginate(Match(Index("result-agg"), $ref)), Lambda("x", Get(Var("x")))))
  main: Select("data", Get($ref))},
  Merge(Var("main"), {results: Var("subs")})
)
```